# Display ASP.NET table row based on RadioButtonList clicked choice using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an ASP.net webform where the selection choice on a RadioButtonList determines what rows to display. There's a jquery script that handles the rows to display or hide and it works.

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $("#<%= rblP.ClientID%> input[type='radio']").click(function () {
            // display appropriate textbox based on clicked radio button
            if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == "1") {
                $('#<%=yes_tr.ClientID %>').show();
                $('#<%=no_tr.ClientID %>').hide();
            } else if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).val() == "2") {
                $('#<%=no_tr.ClientID %>').show();
                $('#<%=yes_tr.ClientID %>').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>SOME TEXT</td>
    <td>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblP" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table"
            Width="150px" Height="20px" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="yes_tr" style="display: none;" runat="server">
    <td>SOME TEXT</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtM" runat="server" Width="201px" MaxLength="35"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="no_tr" style="display: none;" runat="server">
    <td>SOME TEXT</td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtE" runat="server" Width="200px" MaxLength="35"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Unfortunately when I change the textboxes (in the HTML above) to dropdownlists the script hides both "no_tr" and "yes_tr" whenever a selection is made on the dropdowns. How do i modify the script to account to DropDownLists.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlE" runat="server" Width="200px" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

Some coding for the dropdownlist is omitted for simplicity

Comment: The dropdownlists which replace the textbox... do they have the attribute "AutoPostBack" set to "True"?

Comment: 1. set ClientIDMode to static in order to make things easier to find https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: 2. use classes and CSS. It tends to play nicer with JS and HTML than style tags.

Comment: do you plan on accessing, modifying any of this info server side again? if not it is clearer if you use just HTML elements instead of ASP elements.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer setting the attribute "AutoPostBack" to "False" fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Ishey4 - Yes, there are modifications on the server side so the need for ASP elements.